# Configure Citadel to be Used For sending email using smtp

Tags: linux, smtp, linode, citadel

Sorry for this foolish question, but I have less knowldge about servers. So bear with me!

I have configured Citadel as directed in linode documentation and can
login using the front-end for accessing citadel. I can send emails
using that. How can i configure smtp and use it as a mail service for sending
emails from laravel which is a php framework?. Any help will be
appreciated.

I have configured it as

```
Enter 0.0.0.0 for listen address
Select Internal for authentication method
Specify your admin <username>
Enter an admin <password>
Select Internal for web server integration
Enter 80 for Webcit HTTP port
Enter 443 for the Webcit HTTPS port (or enter -1 to disable it)
Select your desired language
```

After this i have entered mail name in **/etc/mailname**  as

```
mail.domain.com
```

and i can access adn sendmail using https://mail.domain.com

My laravel mail.php file
    'driver' => 'smtp',

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Postmark mail service, which will provide reliable delivery.
|
*/

'host' => 'mail.hututoo.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to delivery e-mails to
| users of your application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Postmark e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => 25,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => array('address' => 'no-reply@hututoo.com', 'name' => null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'tls',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => 'passname',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => 'paswwordtest',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/citmail -t',
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "Now i want to use it to send emails from outside like using php."? I don't know what "from outside" means nor do I understand "like using PHP".

Comment: I can't find the exact word but in short what can be done after setting citadel to be used as a mail service. So that from my code i can send mail

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure PHP to send mail to [`citmail`](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/documentation:cmdman:citmail) which should have been included in your Citadel installation. Set its path in `php.ini`:

```
sendmail_path = "/path/to/citmail -t"
```

If you're connecting directly to the server via SMTP then you should use its hostname (or localhost) and port 587 to send mail.

Comment: I did this  but still things are not as expected!i have given host as the url name given in /etc/mailname . port  is 25 username and password of user in citadel.After giving sendmail path things doesn't work even?

Comment: You should post much more details in your question.

Comment: I have updated my code. Take a review!

Comment: @Creator It sounds like you forgot to set `'driver' => 'sendmail'`